# Populate a state variable after an async fetch and the setting of another state variable

Tags: reactjs

In my component initialization I need to do the following steps, in this order:

1. Fetch a server-side data request.
2. Set a state var. with the result.
3. Populate another state var. based on the state var. obtained in (2)

If I do the following

```
const [myData, setMyData] = useState(null);
const [additionalObject, setAdditionalObject] = useState([]);

useEffect(async () => {    
    const response = await axios.get(url); // Step 1
    setMyData(response.data); // Step 2
    populateAdditionalObject(); // Step 3   
}, []); 

// --- Custom Method: ADDITIONAL STATE VAR DEPENDENT ON "myData" ---
const populteAdditionalObject = () => {
    if (myData != null) {
        //... set "additionalObject" as appropriate based on "myData" ...
    }
}
```

I see that the setter in `Step 2` is not immediate, and when I come to `populateAdditionalObject` which checks `myData`, it's not populated yet.

To solve this problem, I added a new `useEffect` pointing to the variable `myData` to track when it changes. I did the following:

```
// On initialization, fetch UserInfo
useEffect(async () => {    
    const response = await axios.get(url); // Step 1
    setMyData(response.data); // Step 2
}, []); 
// On update of myData, populate "additionalObject" state var
useEffect(() => {
    populateAdditionalObject(); 
}, [myData]);
```

This does work, but now I get a warning in the browser, which I didn't have before:

```
 Line 26:5:   React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'populateAdditionalObject'. Either include it or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
```

So how do I solve this with the right sequence and no browser warnings?

Answer (score 1):

Add the function to the dependency array as the warning suggests:

```
useEffect(() => {
  populateAdditionalObject(); 
}, [myData, populateAdditionalObject]);
```

Then to ensure that the function itself doesn't change unless it needs to, wrap it in a `useCallback` with its own dependency array:

```
const populteAdditionalObject = useCallback(() => {
  if (myData != null) {
    //... set "additionalObject" as appropriate based on "myData" ...
  }
}, [myData]);
```

Though the `useEffect` dependency array may also start to complain that it has an unnecessary dependency, `myData`.  (Because `myData` isn't actually used in the effect, at least not directly.)  But since changes to `myData` *should* result in a new instance of the callback, it *should* work with only that in the dependency array:

```
useEffect(() => {
  populateAdditionalObject(); 
}, [populateAdditionalObject]);
```

---

Alternatively, if you don't want to chain the dependencies this much, you can tell the code linter to ignore that dependency array:

```
useEffect(() => {
  populateAdditionalObject();
  // eslint-disable-next-line
}, [myData]);
```

This option should be used sparingly, it's basically your way of saying "I know something about this that the linter/transpiler/etc. doesn't know, trust me."  Which in this case is true, because what you know is that this effect truly should *only* be run when `myData` changes, and that `populateAdditionalObject` is always going to be re-defined on a component render and will always have the correct closures, etc.

That last part is important, and why the dependency for `useCallback` included `myData`.  Because you don't want to call a stale `populateAdditionalObject` with a stale reference to `myData` because you'd end up with the same original problem you had, but more difficult to diagnose.

It's generally best to follow the linter warnings and maintain the dependency arrays completely.  While this option is fine on rare occasions, more often than not I think that suppressing the warnings is covering up what should be a design change.

---

As a possible design change and another alternative, you could skip the second `useEffect` entirely and pass the necessary data to the function:

```
useEffect(async () => {    
  const response = await axios.get(url); // Step 1
  setMyData(response.data); // Step 2
  populateAdditionalObject(response.data); // Step 3   
  // eslint-disable-next-line
}, []);

const populteAdditionalObject = (data) => {
  if (data != null) {
    //... set "additionalObject" as appropriate based on "data" ...
  }
}
```

This is *probably* the simplest approach overall and would be preferred if the function doesn't have some other reason not to accept the data as an argument.  (Something we don't see in the code shown.)

Comment: This still flags `populateAdditionalObject` as a missing dependency. Is there some harm in just including the function as a param, without all the `useCallback` complexity?

Comment: @geneb.: Which option did you go with?  Based on your comment I did just notice that the third option here was missing dependencies, so I added those.  But that may not be what you want?  If that `useEffect` to fetch the data really should only ever happen on the first render of the component, you'll likely need to use the second option above on that `useEffect` call to keep the dependency array empty.  That's pretty much 99% of the time that I use `eslint-disable-next-line` is for a forced empty dependency array on a `useEffect`.

Comment: This is pretty horrible. Cluttering one's code with forced warning ignores just because the designers of React didn't think properly about how to facilitate clean code and clean method calls is a testament to React's immaturity.

Answer (score 0):

Pass populateAdditionalObject function in the useEffect hook

```
useEffect(() => {
populateAdditionalObject(); 
}, [populateAdditionalObject]);
```